# java.lang.LinkageError trying to set up Canoo WebTest using Groovy in IntelliJ

Tags: java, groovy, web-testing, linkage, webtest

Okay, so I'm trying to set up a Canoo WebTest using Groovy in Intellij.

As a simple start I used the example the give on their website, namely

```
import com.canoo.webtest.WebtestCase

class SimpleTest extends WebtestCase {
  void testWebtestOnGoogle() {
    webtest("check that WebTest is Google's top 'WebTest' result") {
      invoke "http://www.google.com", description: "Go to Google (in English)"
      verifyTitle "Google"
      setInputField name: "q", value: "WebTest"
      clickButton "I'm Feeling Lucky"
      verifyTitle "Canoo WebTest"

    }
  }
}
```

Whilst executing this code however, I get the following which containts a Linkage error which says something about different class objects. However, I'm not sure what the problem is or how I can resolve this. Any ideas?

Regards

```
wt.defineTasks:
Trying to override old definition of task retry

wt.webtestMonitor:
     [echo] C:\Users\lputtema\Dropbox\GameMe999\out\production\GameMe999\webtest-resources/tools/WebTestMonitor.groovy

wt.htmlReports.init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\lputtema\Dropbox\GameMe999\out\production\GameMe999\webtest-results\resources
     [copy] Copying 22 files to C:\Users\lputtema\Dropbox\GameMe999\out\production\GameMe999\webtest-results\resources
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\lputtema\Dropbox\GameMe999\out\production\GameMe999\webtest-results
Caught: : java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl.getChildNodes()Lorg/w3c/dom/NodeList;" the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/groovy/tools/RootLoader) of the current class, org/apache/xerces/dom/NodeImpl, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for interface org/w3c/dom/Node have different Class objects for the type getChildNodes used in the signature
: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl.getChildNodes()Lorg/w3c/dom/NodeList;" the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/groovy/tools/RootLoader) of the current class, org/apache/xerces/dom/NodeImpl, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for interface org/w3c/dom/Node have different Class objects for the type getChildNodes used in the signature
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:116)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at com.canoo.webtest.ant.WebtestTask.execute(WebtestTask.java:204)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at com.canoo.webtest.groovy.WebTestBuilder.doInvokeMethod(WebTestBuilder.java:54)
    at com.canoo.webtest.WebtestCase.webtest(WebtestCase.groovy:105)
    at com.canoo.webtest.WebtestCase$webtest.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at WebTest.SimpleTest.testWebtestOnGoogle(SimpleTest.groovy:14)
    at WebTest.SimpleTest$testWebtestOnGoogle.call(Unknown Source)
    at WebTest.main.run(main.groovy:12)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:115)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl.getChildNodes()Lorg/w3c/dom/NodeList;" the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/groovy/tools/RootLoader) of the current class, org/apache/xerces/dom/NodeImpl, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for interface org/w3c/dom/Node have different Class objects for the type getChildNodes used in the signature
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.loadConfiguration(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:211)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.loadConfiguration(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:185)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.<init>(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:142)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.getInstance(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:237)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.<init>(JavaScriptEngine.java:116)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.init(WebClient.java:219)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<init>(WebClient.java:193)
    at com.canoo.webtest.engine.Configuration.setupWebClient(Configuration.java:760)
    at com.canoo.webtest.engine.Configuration.createWebClient(Configuration.java:617)
    at com.canoo.webtest.engine.Configuration.setupWebClient(Configuration.java:180)
    at com.canoo.webtest.engine.Configuration.execute(Configuration.java:162)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    ... 11 more

wt.htmlReports:
     [echo] Waiting for completion of background generation of single reports
     [echo] Generating WebTestOverview

wt.openResultFile:
     [echo] Opening result file C:\Users\lputtema\Dropbox\GameMe999\out\production\GameMe999\webtest-results\index.html with cmd
```

Comment: You have different versions of `org/w3c/dom/NodeList` in your classpath

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. I understand the problem, though I'm not sure how to resolve it. I tried deleting jars from the classpath but each time either I'm missing something or I have the above problem (with possibly a different class, e.g. org/w3c/dom/NamedNodeMap). I'm using Groovy-2.2.1 and jdk1.7.0_51

Comment: Have you got 2 differing versions of `xml-apis`?

Comment: Tx for your swift reply. I use jdk1.7.0_51 (not sure if it contains xml-apis) and the xml-library that is in the build.zip of Canoo: xml-apis-1.3.04.jar. Deleting the latter still results in the same error though. PS: next to the jdk I've imported the libs which are in http://webtest.canoo.com/webtest/build.zip

Comment: Okay, managed to sort it out. Had to put 'xercesImpl' and 'xml-apis' in the java endorsed directory ('java\jdk\jre\lib\endorsed'). Tx @tim_yates for the help!